# Is there any way to reduce the options in "Create a new sub site form"?

Tags: site-collection, publishing-site, sub-site, site-settings

Is there any way to reduce the number of fields to enter during site creation. Just have to enter the name, description and URL name. Template selection option should be one rather than all the options with all tabs. Secondly, it uses by default "same permission as parent site".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the template of the sub site by doing the following.

1. Activate publishing features.
2. Go to **Site settings** --> **Page Layouts & Site Template** (under Look & Feel).
3. In the Subsite Templates --> Select "*Subsites can only use the following site templates*".
4. In the box below add only your custom site template.

[image]

Now in your Subsite creation page, there will be only one template option available.

Comment: thanks Unnie for replying. I have tried you solution but it seem that I  don't have options such as Page Layout and Site Template (Under Look &b Feel. I have turn on SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure (under Site collectionj Feature). and I am using SharePoint 2016.

Comment: Did you activated "SharePoint server publishing" feature at site level also.

Comment: Thanks a lot vishal and Unnie, I have done it. really helpful!!

Comment: Is that possible to set site permission and navigation automatically. Means the site creator don't need to select these option?